# Population Proportion help. Is it me? or this question.

Tags: statistics

A study found that, in 2005, 12.5% of U.S. workers belonged to unions (The Wall Street Journal, January 21, 2006). Suppose a sample of 400 U.S. workers is collected in 2006 to determine whether union efforts to organize have increased union membership.

$H_o: p \le 0.125$

$Ha: p > 0.125$

Sample proportion of workers belonging to unions = 51/400 = 0.13 (round to two decimal places)

**Here is the part I'm stuck at:**

Compute the value of the test statistic

The formula I used: $(0.13-0.125)/\sqrt{0.125(1-0.125)/400}    =   0.30$

It says the answer I got was incorrect? I look inside my text and can't find any more help other than this formula? Anyone have a clue? Or is it my online class website that is the issue?

SOLUTION: Instead of using 0.13 in the formula use 0.1275 (51/300 = 1275). I used 0.13 because the previous question told me to round to two decimal places and this made me think i was suppose to do the same thing in the following portion of the question. My mistake.

Comment: What was the answer in your book?

Comment: @browngreen There is no answer in the book :(

Comment: So how do you know it's incorrect?

Comment: @browngreen Its an online class so when i punch the answer in it tells me if its correct or not, but doesn't give me the answer if its incorrect. Anyways i figured what i did wrong and will update the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Specifically, for a one-sided test $$H_0 : p = p_0 \quad \text{vs.} \quad H_a : p > p_0$$ of a binomial proportion with $np_0, n(1-p_0) > 30$ (as in your case), a test statistic would be $$Z \mid H_0 = \frac{\hat p - p_0}{\sqrt{p_0(1-p_0)/n}} \sim \operatorname{Normal}(0,1),$$ where $p_0 = 0.125$ is the hypothesized proportion, $\hat p = 51/400$ is the sample proportion observed, and $n = 400$ is the sample size.  Since $np_0 = 51 > 30$, we can use the above formula to obtain $$Z \mid H_0 = \frac{0.1275 - 0.125}{\sqrt{0.125(1 - 0.125)/400}} = \frac{0.0025}{\sqrt{0.000273438}} = 0.151186.$$  The $p$-value associated with this test is $$\Pr[Z > .151186 \mid H_0] = 0.439915.$$

---

The reason why you obtained an incorrect result appears to be because you improperly rounded the sample proportion $\hat p$.  The denominator of the test statistic is very small, therefore you cannot round $51/400 \approx 0.13$.  It seems inconsequential at first glance, but the denominator is only $0.0165359$, and the difference in the numerator due to rounding to the second decimal place is $0.0025$, which results in a *doubling* of the test statistic's value.

Comment: Haha yea i just figured this out right as you posted it, Thanks for the help anyways pal.

Comment: @Jake Hi Jake, I did not post this answer but I think you should know of the possibility that you could vote up and or accept an answer (by clicking the appropriate icon at the left). This on one hand gives points to the person who posted the answer (and to you too as a matter of fact, and is a more "official" kind of saying thanks), and also labels the question as being already answered, so others would know (when they just browse the list of all questions).